# What will be the name of this sorting algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, hashtable

It is some what identical to what we do in hashing , and after adding elements inn the hash table i am simply searching for each element in in decreasing order and removing the element if it is found after printing it , i used it in solving [Following](http://www.codechef.com/problems/TSORT) very easy problem on codechef here is the basic algo that i had used , but i want to know what is it called ?

```
func(int nos){
     int arr[1000000] = {0};
     while( nos-- ) {
        int k;
        cin>>k;
        arr[k]++;
     }
     for( i=0 ; i<1000000; ) {
        if( arr[i]==0 )
        {
         i++;
         continue;
        }
        cout<<i<<endl;
        arr[i]--;
    }
    }
```

Thanks !

Comment: I think this is somthing like radixsort or Distributionsort http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as [counting sort](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Comment: @gotqn the question is what is the name of the algorithm and I provide a complete answer to that

Comment: my fault - sorry about this.